# Hosting HTTPS nodejs server on Apache server

Tags: node.js, apache, express, ssl, port

I have a nodejs app hosted on WHM/cPanel that uses it's own SSL certificate. Set up:

```
app.all('*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
})

let server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);

const httpsServer = https.createServer(sslFiles, app);
httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log("started")
});
```

When starting the server up I get the error:

```
Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:443
```

There is only one other service running on port 443 which is httpd, I have amended the virtual hosts with a pre-include of:

```
<VirtualHost 123.4.567.890:443>
    ServerName website.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.website.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /root/public_html/

    ErrorLog /root/logs/vherror.log

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://123.4.567.890:3000
    ProxyPassReverse / https://123.4.567.890:3000
    ProxyPreserveHost On    

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLUseStapling Off
    SSLCertificateFile /root/etc/website.co.uk/ssl/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/etc/website.co.uk/ssl/theKey.key
</VirtualHost>
```

This pre-include worked for about 2 weeks and fixed the error but suddenly it has stopped working and I am receiving the port error again and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm thinking it might be due to Cloudflare since I've set that up today, but I've turned all Cloudflare settings to DNS only and I still receive the error. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changed the vhost file proxypass and proxypassreverse to use website name instead of IP and then changed the SSL port used on nodejs server to 4433 and it seems to be working fine now.